# cannot save new generated file vscode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, visual-studio-code, save

I'm trying to make a vscode extension. One functionnality it will need is creating a new file that the user can modify and then save. I use the following code to do so :

```
export async function linkA() {

const newFile = Uri.parse('untitled:' + path.join(workspace.workspaceFolders![0].uri.path + "/templates", 'filename.txt'));

workspace.openTextDocument(newFile).then(async document => {

    const edit = new WorkspaceEdit();

    edit.insert(newFile, new Position(0, 0), "Hello world!");

    return workspace.applyEdit(edit).then(success => {
        if (success) {
            window.showTextDocument(document);
        } else {
            window.showInformationMessage('Error!');
        }
    }); });}
```

When the function linkA is called, this does open a new file "filename.txt" and I can edit it. But when I try to save it I get the following error message (as a vscode information window ) :
Failed to save 'filename.txt': Unable to write file '\c:\Users\RAM\Desktop\vscode-extension-samples\helloworld-sample\templates\filename.txt' (EntryNotFound (FileSystemError): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\c:\Users\RAM\Desktop\vscode-extension-samples\helloworld-sample\templates\filename.txt').

Anybody knows how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: don't use `Uri.parse` to create a fileURL, it is a file so why use scheme `untitled`, why don't you create the file first before opening

Comment: I'm quite new coding in js/ts. How would you do that ?

Comment: there is an `fs` object in the VSC API to interact with file systems, methods are very similar to node `fs` module